# Формулировка действия кнопки "откат" в меню просмотра версий поста

Tags: предложение, локализация, правки, дизайн

При просмотре версий поста у всех версий, кроме самой новой, есть кнопка "откат":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, что в имеющейся формулировке это слово не очень правильно описывает то действие, которое обозначает.

По моим представлениям, "откат" обозначает скорее отмену какого-либо изменения, а не отмену **до какого-либо** изменения, и только по отсутствию этой кнопки у самой новой версии поста можно догадаться до действительно имеющегося смысла.

В связи с этим предложение уточнить надпись на кнопке до "откатить до этой версии" или чего-то подобного, но более содержательного, чем просто "откат".

Comment: Хм.. Когда я первый раз пользовался откатом, у меня почему-то сомнений на тему куда жать не было - всё понял правильно. Скорее всего, свою роль сыграло то, что откатить только одну версию из середины нельзя, а кнопки есть везде. Хотя, само по себе слово "откат" действительно ассоциируется с действием.

Comment: @Qwertiy я в первый раз подумал, что это откат какого-то конкретного изменения, что-то вроде отката изменений конкретного коммита. В итоге из-за отсутствия кнопки на самом последнем изменении догадался об истинном её назначении. Думаю, многие новички могут столкнуться с этим.

Answer (score 2):

Изменить надпись на

> "откатить до этой версии".

Comment: Учитывая, что пунктов в меню очень мало, проблем с длинной надписью нет, поэтому можно не экономить на буквах.

Comment: @Discord, тем не менее, длинная фраза не сочетается с соседними однословными.

Comment: Может быть, благозвучнее «откатить к этой версии»?

Comment: @VladD: публикуйте как ответ, хороший вариант.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Сделал.

Answer (score 1):

> «вернуть к этой версии»

Comment: В таком случае нужно править и описание значка, хотя его нужно править в любом случае)

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev нам не впервой, поправим)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант из комментариев:

> откатить к этой версии

Comment: проголосовал :)

Answer (score 0):

Оставить имеющуюся надпись "откат", описанной проблемы на самом деле нет.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, такой вариант подойдёт:

> откатить сюда

Не очень точная фраза, зато не так длинно.

Comment: Да, я думал о проблеме с длиной, но с другой стороны там места крайне много

Answer (score 0):

Воз и ныне там, поэтому предложу просто заменить существительное глаголом:

> откатить

А подробное описание того, что реально происходит ([почти](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3743/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) всегда доступно в хинте. Поэтому не надо переносить лишний текст на экран для принудительного просмотра (т.е. без наведения мыши).