# Пропал перевод подсказки действия отката сообщения

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

При наведении мыши на пункт "откат" в списке версии [сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/568660/revisions) всплывающая подсказка не переведена:

[image: rollback]

При этом, в Transifex был перевод для фразы:

> sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "offensive" flags

> применяет текущую редакцию к данной версии сообщения, сбрасывая все отметки «оскорбление»

Такой фразы теперь [нет](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/94712506?q=set%20the%20current%20revision). Т.е. видимо на enSO решили заменить "offensive" на "rude or abusive" а мы теперь из-за этого "наслаждаемся" отсутствием перевода там, где он уже когда-то был. Ситуация, честно говоря, не из очень приятных - делать одну и ту же работу несколько раз. Особенно учитывая, что в качестве перевода можно оставить прежнюю версию, если не окунаться в дословность.

Хотелось бы в будущем избегать таких ситуаций, поэтому предлагаю обсудить возможные идеи для исключения "сброса" переводов по инициативе сообщества enSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю оставить прежний перевод, несмотря на то, что исходная строка несколько изменилась.

> применяет текущую редакцию к данной версии сообщения, сбрасывая все отметки «оскорбление»